# Random forest does not seem to handle more than 32 categories of factors. What do I do to include these factors in training my model?

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, random-forest

I am trying to train Random forest on my training data which has predictors like 'names', 'city'. These two predictors have more than 32 categories. What do I do to include them?

Even some other algorithms does not seem to handle larger categories like SVM or gbm.

Comment: (1) 32 binary variables, or (2) Collapse the variable down to fewer categories. The limitation is a technical one in this case, but variables with enormous numbers of categories can be problematic statistically, since it is often a sign that very little thought has gone into your data selection and prep.

Comment: Alternatively, do not use those variables but the other one you have gathered.

Comment: @joran How is using all 50 US states e.g. a "sign that very little thought has gone into" the selection of data? How might you categorize/group these variables?

Comment: @Gaffi 50 states might be reasonable in some cases, depending on the model. But that's your example, not mine, and not the OP's, who only references name and city (which in my mind implied a lot more than 50). In general, variables with extremely large numbers of categories tend not to be very informative due to sample size and estimability issues. But there are exceptions to everything.

Comment: @joran I guess my point is that I have the same issue as the OP, but I'm not sure how to work with all 50 states. How else might you put these predictors together? Split down to 25/25 and run two different analyses?

Comment: @Gaffi Maybe. Depends on how sure you are that each state will really be meaningfully different. Do you really think that, say, VT is going to be enough different from NH or ME that it warrants a separate category? Maybe you can group the states into regions/groups of similar states.

Comment: @joran We're talking medical bill processing guidelines, so yes, in some cases the difference from one state to the next will be very significant. I believe some grouping can be achieved, but I don't have the knowledge of each state's rules to delve into that...

Answer (score 2):

It is generally recommended to avoid using the formula interface to randomforest anyway for reasons of speed.  Instead, use `model.matrix` with your formula, and feed the result of that to randomforest.  Then you can have as many categories as you'd like, since they are dichotomized (i.e. dummied out or turned into binary variables).

As @joran pointed out, you might want to think about your problem more as well.

Comment: this answer saved my life :)

Comment: Happy to help :-)